# Chinese localization not worked with PHP gettext extension as it works with English

Tags: php, apache, localization, gettext, chinese-locale

I'm already localized a website from Russian to English with PHP and gettext just with wrapping all strings into `__($string)` function.

It works.

Here's the gists: https://gist.github.com/Grawl/ba8f39b8398791c6a67e

But it don't work with Chinese translation. I just added compiled `.mo` (and source `.po`) into `locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/`, visit `/index.php?locale=zh_CN` and don't see it translated at all.

What it wrong with Chinese?

Have I to use other language code or something?

I use `zh_CN` to map on Chinese like it done in WordPress.

*I cannot understand **why**.*

---

**Update:**

The problem was in HTML `<meta>` tag and charset going from server in `Windows-1251`. *Chop russian PHP server.*

After I set `<meta charset="GBK">` and turned off `AddDefaultCharset` in `.htaccess`, Chinese localization finally started to work.

After all, I added these modifications:

`.htaccess`:

```
- AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
+ AddDefaultCharset off
+ RewriteRule ^cn index.php?locale=zh_CN&charset=GBK [L]
```

`functions.php`, included before `<!DOCTYPE html>`:

```
+ $charset=$_GET["charset"];
+ if(!isset($charset)) {
+   $charset="UTF-8";
+ }
```

`head.php`, the `<head>` tag content:

```
+ <meta charset="<?=$charset?>">
```

So, if I does not set charset into get request, it becomes UTF-8, otherwise it goes from get request. For Chiense I set it to `GBK`, like on Taobao.com, and browser sets up right charset.

**But after all I just has cyrillic characters encoded in Chinese glyphs, character by character.**

Like this: `Сервис и услуги`

Becomes this: `褋械褉胁懈褋 懈 褍褋谢褍谐懈`

If you paste these Chinese characters into [decoder app](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/), chose GB2312 on left (one from Chinese charsets) and UTF-8 on right, you will have `?е?ви? и ??л?ги` – some cyrillic characters corrupted but this is obviously an original string, because in translation I have more shorten `服务` for this phrase.

**Help me please.**

---

**Update 2**

I just forgot to set `bind_textdomain_codeset();` to `$domain`, it was `messages`.

All works on unicode charset. All normal.

Comment: Your gist doesn't show the Chinese message catalogue. So, impossible to guess. And for the system gettext library to pick it up, you'd often have to restart the mod_php/PHP-FPM process.

Comment: @mario yes, it's old gists when I done only English l10n

Comment: Do you have the Chinese locale installed...?

Comment: @deceze did you read my question at all?

Comment: "Locale" as in *the system libraries necessary for this locale*. Not the .mo file.

Comment: @deceze should I really ask server administrator to install something just to swap some strings? :(

Comment: It's necessary  for the `setlocale` call to work, which gettext depends on, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Summary

I was able to make this work without changing the `<meta charset="...">` value away from `utf-8`. You should also be able to remove the `AddDefaultCharset` rule from your `.htaccess` and also remove the `&charset=GBK` from your `RewriteRule`. You need to make sure that your `.po` file is formatted and compiled correctly, and also make sure that server can find it.

### Explanation/Example

Setting the `<meta charset="...">` tag only tells the **browser** what character encoding is being used on the page. PHP still needs to know which file to select to replace strings. And in any case, although [this documentation suggests otherwise](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Header-Entry.html), I think you can still use `UTF-8` to do Chinese localization. Here is a simple working example I set up on my system:

```
<?php
    // initialize locale-related variables
    $locale     = $_GET['locale'] ?: 'en_US';
    $domain     = 'bridges';
    $locale_dir = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/locale'; // using absolute path!

    // set up locale
    putenv( "LC_ALL=$locale" );
    setlocale( LC_ALL, $locale );
    bindtextdomain( $domain, $locale_dir );
    bind_textdomain_codeset( $domain, 'UTF-8' );
    textdomain($domain);
?><!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?= _( 'Localization Test' ) ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?= _( 'Hello' ) ?>!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My `.po` file which is located at `./locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/bridges.po` looks like:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: 1.0\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-07-20\n"
"Last-Translator: Morgan Benton\n"
"Language-Team: Chinese\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Language: zh_CN\n"

msgid "Localization Test"
msgstr "本土化试"

msgid "Hello"
msgstr "您好"
```

According to a [comment on the `gettext()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#91650), you should put the character encoding and other relevant headers inside your `.po` file, e.g.

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

You can check the syntax of your `.po` file by running the command `msgfmt -c bridges.po -o bridges.mo` from your terminal. It will warn you if it thinks anything is wrong with your `.po` file. As the commenter suggested, I think you do NOT need to have the Chinese system libraries installed.

P.S. I don't know if these Chinese translations are correct or not. This is just what Google Translate gave me! :)

Comment: You are showing me the way I'm started before I tried to make something strange with all these encodings and charsets. Actually all exactly the same, except absolute path. It don't works if I try to use something other than `./locale`.

Comment: I generate my `.mo` file with Poedit and cannot do anything with `.po` if it is not valid. I tried to change encoding to `utf-16` with IDE and open it in Poedit after but no, Poedit don't want to work with non-UTF-8.

Comment: Oh crap I just forgot to set `bind_textdomain_codeset();` to `$domain`, it was `messages`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sure. It always is something small.

Comment: @Grawl "Poedit don't want to work with non-UTF-8" — this is simply not true, Poedit works perfectly fine with any common charset. You must have messed it up (such as lying about the actual file's charset in the `Content-Type` header).